# Refused to load the script 'https://utteranc.es/client.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: next.js

I am receiving the error as shown below when inserting the utteranc.es commenting system into my site. How can I solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FtUR.png)

and below is next.config.js

```js
// https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
    default-src 'self';
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.youtube.com *.twitter.com utteranc.es;
    child-src *.youtube.com *.google.com *.twitter.com utteranc.es;
    frame-src utteranc.es;
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.googleapis.com;
    img-src * blob: data:;
    media-src 'none';
    connect-src *;
    font-src 'self';
`;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `utteranc.es` at the end of the `script-src` line with a space after `*.twitter.com`?

Comment: @Nelloverflow i added `utteranc.es` to `script-src`, `child-src` and `frame-src`. It's exported in the browser's developer tools, but not on the screen.

Comment: Remember that you need to restart your development server for changes in `next.config.js` to take effect.

Comment: @juliomalves I have restarted the development server but it still doesn't show up and this is the error https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QLcN.png

Comment: That error seems to be caused by a Chrome extension. Can you reproduce the issue in Incognito mode (or with extensions disabled)?

Comment: Thanks, @juliomalves I used a browser with no extensions installed and no errors. `<iframe>` has been added but it still doesn't show up and just appears as a blank area in the browser.